# Adding Text Box to Angular Form

Tags: angularjs, forms, dynamic, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to dynamically add a textbox to an Angular form.  I'm using ng-repeat and I can add the text box easily by just pushing, an empty string to the array.  It will add another textbox, the problem is that ng-model is not syncing the data, and when text is added it remains an empty string.

The text boxes that get created from the initial array sync just fine, it's just the newly added text boxes that are not working.

I've been looking around and one suggestion I saw was to always use a "." when using ng-model, but that didn't work for me.

```
    <div ng-repeat="text in image.text track by $index">

      <md-input-container class="md-block" novalidate>
      <label>Text {{$index + 1}}:</label>

        <textarea md-maxlength="2500" md-midlength="1" required md-no-asterisk name="text"
        placeholder="{{text}}"
        ng-model="text"></textarea> 
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
```

Controller:

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('app.article')
    .controller('ArticleEditController', ArticleEditController);

ArticleEditController.$inject= ['articleEditDataService', '$routeParams', '$log'];   

function ArticleEditController(articleEditDataService, $routeParams, $log) {
    var vm = this;

    var site = $routeParams.site;
    var articleName = $routeParams.article;
    var articleRevision_id = $routeParams.revision_id;

    vm.data = {};
    vm.addNewText = addNewText;
    vm.removeText = removeText;
    vm.saveArticle = saveArticle;
    vm.numMessage = 1;

    activate();

    function activate(){
        getArticle();
    }

    function getArticle(){
        var data = articleEditDataService.getArticle(site, articleName, articleRevision_id);
        data.then(function successResponse(res) {
            vm.data = res.results.data;
        }, function errorResponse (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }

    function saveArticle(){
        var article = articleEditDataService.postArticle(vm.data, site, articleName, articleRevision_id);
        console.log(vm.data);
        article
            .then(updateArticleSuccess)
            .catch(updateArticleError);
    }

    function updateArticleSuccess(message){
        $log.info(message);
    }

    function updateArticleError(errorMessage){
        $log.error(errorMessage);
    }


    function addNewText (index, key) {
      vm.data.content.image_sets[key].text.push("");
    }

    function removeText (index, key) {
      if(vm.data.content.image_sets[key].text.length > 1){
        vm.data.content.image_sets[key].text.pop();
      }
    }


};
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

initialize the model variable within your controller as an empty object.

then within your text input your ng-model="model[$index]".